# What is the meaning of a dynamic type of some value in go?

Tags: types, go

Considering the fact that [go](/questions/tagged/go) is **statically** typed language, What is the meaning of a dynamic type of some value ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The 'dynamic type' of a variable is important when handling interface values.
Dynamic types are defined as follows ([source](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)):

> The static type (or just type) of a variable is the type defined by its declaration. **Variables of interface type also have a distinct dynamic type, which is the actual type of the value stored in the variable at run time.** The dynamic type may vary during execution but is always assignable to the static type of the interface variable. For non-interface types, the dynamic type is always the static type.

Consider this example:

```
var someValue interface{} = 2
```

The static type of `someValue` is `interface{}` but the dynamic type is `int` and may very
well change in the future. Example:

```
var someValue interface{} = 2

someValue = "foo"
```

In the example above the dynamic type of `someValue` changed from `int` to `string`.